# How to get unique records from multiple tables based on multiple columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
contacts1

id  name    email
1   sachin  sachin@gmail.com
2   amit    sachin@gmail.com
2   rahul   rahul@yahoo.com

contacts2

id  name    email
1   neha    neha@gmail.com
2   sachin  sachin@gmail.com
3   mukesh  mukesh@yahoo.com

contacts3 

id  name        email
1   pooja       pooja@gmail.com
2   mukeshkumar mukesh@yahoo.com
3   amit        amit@gmail.com
```

I want to get unique records (EMAIL COLUMN)  from these 3 tables. I used `UNION` as

```
SELECT `name`, `email` FROM `contacts1` WHERE `email` != '' 
UNION 
SELECT `name`, `email` FROM `contacts2` WHERE `email` != '' 
UNION 
SELECT `name`, `email` FROM `contacts3` WHERE `email` != ''
```

**Output**

[image]

The two records in result set have same email id (red cross mark). I want to exclude them and get only their first occurrence. I tried `DISTINCT` for `email` field but it gave me an error. How can we do that?

I want to achieve this

[image]

Comment: First note, the `id` column values should be unique in each table. Maybe you have another auto-increment column?

Comment: @SloanThrasher, no, its not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using sub query with group by like this:

```
SELECT M.* FROM (
    SELECT `name`, `email` FROM `contacts1` WHERE `email` != '' 
    UNION 
    SELECT `name`, `email` FROM `contacts2` WHERE `email` != '' 
    UNION 
    SELECT `name`, `email` FROM `contacts3` WHERE `email` != '' 
) AS M
GROUP BY M.`email`
```

Comment: Close, but this will not return the "first" as the OP requests. But the OP doesn't define what "first" means. Maybe the lowest value for `id`? If so, you would also need to add an `ORDER BY` on `id`.

Comment: Yes. But base on my test, MySQL GROUP BY will return the first occurrence when you select a certain column. And also base on the sample data, those 3 tables have same or similar ID values so we cant assure the first occurrence result if we use order by.

Comment: I don't know why @JonelZape answer is marked negative. "first" I meant the record with lowest id if two email addresses are same, yes right.

Comment: `id` has nothing to deal here with my question of email field uniqueness.

Comment: @Sachin There is no problem in SQL for which the above (a GROUP BY clause absent of any aggregating functions) is a valid solution, but hey, it's your party.

Comment: @JonelZape and others, without the `ORDER BY` clause, the result is considered *indeterminate*, that is, if you run the query many, many times, you may get different results. The `ORDER BY` clause does no harm, and ultimately will make the query consistant.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I get you point there that must have ID or something that can determine the min and max for correct order purposes for the `name` column. But as you can see on the sample data shows that it came from different tables with no unique  ID and have same ID when you combine them so we cant use order by to determine what name should appear on the result. But I guess the question is very simple, display the unique email and that's it.

Comment: It's easy enough to add the `id` column to the  selects that are UNIONed, thus allowing you to use it for the order by. The point is that over time, without an order by, your results will not be consistent. Consider it a best practice kind of thing.

Comment: Yes I agree @SloanThrasher. This solution will work for now for this scenario. But please Sachin also consider doing best practices and table structures. Happy coding :)